# Tinder-like search based on distance in Flutter - Most efficient way?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, distance, back4app, geohashing

Imagine an app very similar to Tinder, match users with similar interests, but **only in a certain radius**.

I guess similar question to this, but specifically for Flutter:
[How to implement a tinder-like search based on distance in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378391/how-to-implement-a-tinder-like-search-based-on-distance-in-android)

---

The most basic idea is to just save each user's lat & long in Firestore upon app start. Then query the first e.g. 10 users from db and calculate the distance between them with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230131/how-to-set-distance-between-users-using-geolocator-in-flutter).

Is this all I need? I suppose I won't need something big like [geoflutterfire](https://geoflutterfire) with map visualization and whatnot. All I need is the location of each user.

### **So my questions are:**

1. Is [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) the best plugin for this? Or is there something specifically suited?
2. Is this a feasible solution for a big amount of users?

I'm worried that calculating the distance in this way will become impossible, since the app will be loading for minutes.

Or maybe I have to lean into [geohashing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries)? But that would mean I have to use geoflutterfire, am I then bound by the API calls restriction of Google Maps?

---

**Edit:** Seeing this question: [Flutter Firestore Geo query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674470/flutter-firestore-geo-query), it seems like Firestore may be a bad solution for this?
Am I forced to migrate to something like [Back4App](https://www.back4app.com/backend-as-a-service-baas) which has things like `withinGeoBox`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's also possible to do it with [geohashing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uhSpLjGLgo).

you can do that with https://pub.dev/packages/geohash_plus

Comment: Thank you for the video, was educational. That plugin seems a little ill-documented, so I'll look around a bit more. In this question & answer here he seems to make it work with the fluttergeofire plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682953/flutter-firebase-get-docs-by-geohash